# Create multiple records from a single record, with one field based on a second table

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-forms

I'm completely new to creating MS Access databases, so please bear with me while I ask my (probably silly) question.

I have a table for commodities that also groups them into CropGroup and Class, and every commodity would also be considered 'Any food'.

***Commodity table:***
[image]

I would like to add one entry (maybe in a form?), with fields like 'Country' 'Commodity' 'Metal' 'Limit' with all fields identical other than the commodity. Rather than entering these manually for each commodity, is there a way that I can specify the country, metal and limit, select 'Fruit' or 'Anyfood' to automatically create a record for each commodity associated with these terms, so it looks similar to this? Doing this would save me hours if not days of work in the long term.

***Output table:***
[image]

Any suggestions or pointers in the right directions would be much appreciated!

Cheers,
Sophie

Comment: In data entry form you can set default value of text/combo boxes. So, when you will create new record text boxes will fill with default value automatically.

Comment: If you want the inputs in a session to carry forward to subsequent records, use code (macro or VBA) in each control's AfterUpdate event to set its DefaultValue property. Each time user enters data, the code will reset DefaultValue property and carry forward to subsequent new records.

Comment: For a DefaultValue to be applied, there must be data input to at least one control of new record.

Comment: If you want to 'batch' create a bunch of records in one action, that is an entirely different situation.

Comment: Here is one example of batch creating records https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372889/how-to-use-a-insert-into-select-query-in-access-vb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set default value for text or comboboxes in data entry form.
[image]

So, you will set default value for each text box individually. When you you will run the form, text boxes will fill with default values automatically. If need you can then change values as per your need. As per my above screenshot, when you run the data entry form it will look like-

[image]

Comment: This is such an easy way of doing it! Cheers!

Comment: If it helps, then please mark the answer (tick mark it).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across to this question later, I was able to solve this perfectly with a relatively simple SQL query in the end:

```
INSERT INTO MetalLimits ( Country, Commodity, Element, [Limit(mg/kg)] )
SELECT Country, Commodity, Element, [Limit(mg/kg)]

FROM (SELECT Commodity FROM _CommodityList 
WHERE (([_CommodityList].CropGroup) Like [Enter CropGroup] & "*") AND 
(([_CommodityList].Class) Like [Enter Class] & "*")) ;
```

This allows manually entering Country, Element and Limit(mg/kg) as per the table rules (for MetalLimits table) in separate prompt pop-ups, and select the commodities based on the pre-defined CropGroup and Class (from _CommodityList) in another pop-up.