# Trying to add multiple records based on information in one form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

[Relationship graph for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxrXm.png)

I currently have a [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHHRp.png) that adds a new record into my *Games* table which, among other things, includes the two teams that played. Where I'm stuck, and what I'm looking to do is:

- add records for every skater (Position ID 1 & 2) that played in the game, which would be found by the two teams selected in the original form
- add records for every goalie (Position ID 3) as stated above
- open a form listing all the newly-added skater records showing the player name and fields to enter
- open a form listing all the newly-added goalie records as stated above

I've got the original Game Entry Form set up to properly show team names, but that's about the most complex thing I've done. I'm an expert Excel user but I'm brand new to Access. I'm not sure if or how to pass information or make queries that may do what I need to do here. I'm also not sure how to make the form show just the newly added records. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Question is too broad and concerns more than just programming - involves design of objects - and is not suited to SO. Might want to post in a discussion forum that allows attaching files.

Comment: If you want to 'batch' create records, that is a fairly common topic and will probably involve VBA executing INSERT SELECT action SQL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/insert-update-and-delete-records-from-a-table-using-access-sql#insert-records-into-a-table and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372889/how-to-use-a-insert-into-select-query-in-access-vb

Comment: use docmd.openForm formname to open the forms when you are ready.  to insert multiple records see here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70175837/populating-multiple-fields-in-subform-using-combobox-and-afterupdate-event-prodc/70184495#70184495

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.