# MS Access, write multiple new records based off query results and user enterable fields for new values

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I have created a MS Access data base to keep track of our Firmware releases.

This allows us to go back and see what date a specific firmware version was released.

*So far I've only entered random data to verify functionality of forms / tables / queries.*

Part of releasing new firmware we do quarterly "Mass Updates" where all firmware's that match specific criteria's are updated.

I've generated a form that allows the user to enter the follow:

- New version   (Example = 5.0.2)

Along with selecting the following criteria:

- Category (Example = Graphical Series) - this is a drop down with pre defined items
- Processor (Example = Renesas) - this is a drop down with pre defined items
- Released By  (Example = D.Booth) - this is a drop down with pre defined items

[Mass Update Entry Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5fT1.png)

Bases on the criteria selected above (Category & Processor) Access returns a Query with all records.

[Mass Update Record Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9c9I.png)

My question is how can I take that list generated by the Query and write a new record for each item adding the (New Version) and a hidden date field that defaults "Now()" as a time stamp?

These new records would be entered into the "Data - Firmware Revisions" table.

[Data - Firmware Revisions Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwSbo.png)

I'm assuming this would be done using SQL or VBA but unsure where to start.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to 'batch' create records using existing records as a template as well as incorporating new values, consider an INSERT INTO SELECT action SQL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372889/how-to-use-a-insert-into-select-query-in-access-vba

Answer (score 0):

This seems to boil down to the common question of how to do rapid data entry.  As the forms/subforms approach access provides for rapid form creation only allows editing single values.  Indeed, vba is needed.  For instance the approach I see and use most often to create a standard access form of the table to which you want to add/update records, so you can follow the changes.

Add some unbound controls to the header to control what records you want to add or update and some buttons to run the code.  For example,

```
-------------------------------------------
|     CategoryID     | CategoryDescription |
-------------------------------------------
|                  1 | A                  |
-------------------------------------------
|                  2 | B                  |
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------------
|    ProcessorID     |         ProcessorDescription         |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | Intel                                |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | AMD                                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FirmWareRevisionID |      Version       |      Category      |     Processor      |    RevisionDate    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | 1                  |                  1 |                  1 |          1/22/2024 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | 1                  |                  2 |                  1 |          1/22/2024 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 | 1                  |                  1 |                  2 |          1/22/2024 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 | 1                  |                  2 |                  2 |          1/22/2024 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: form to add multiple records]

```
Private Sub cmbCategory_AfterUpdate()
Dim filter As String
If IsNull(Me.cmbCategory) And IsNull(Me.cmbProcessor) Then
filter = "" 'no filter selected
ElseIf IsNull(Me.cmbCategory) Then
filter = "Processor = " & Me.cmbProcessor
ElseIf IsNull(Me.cmbProcessor) Then
filter = "Category = " & Me.cmbCategory
Else
filter = "Category = " & Me.cmbCategory & " AND Processor = " & Me.cmbProcessor
End If
Me.filter = filter
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmbProcessor_AfterUpdate()
Dim filter As String
If IsNull(Me.cmbCategory) And IsNull(Me.cmbProcessor) Then
filter = "" 'no filter selected
ElseIf IsNull(Me.cmbCategory) Then
filter = "Processor = " & Me.cmbProcessor
ElseIf IsNull(Me.cmbProcessor) Then
filter = "Category = " & Me.cmbCategory
Else
filter = "Category = " & Me.cmbCategory & " AND Processor = " & Me.cmbProcessor
End If
Me.filter = filter
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAddVersion_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim rsRevisions As Recordset
Dim rsForm As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsRevisions = db.OpenRecordset("FirmwareRevisions")
Set rsForm = Me.RecordsetClone() 'you can do whatever you want to the clone
Dim row As Integer
For row = 0 To rsForm.RecordCount() 'interate through filtered records adding a corresponding new version
rsRevisions.AddNew
rsRevisions!Category = Category
rsRevisions!Processor = Processor
rsRevisions!Version = Me.txtVersion
rsRevisions!RevisionDate = Now()
rsRevisions.Update
row = row + 1
Next row
'cleanup
Set rsForm = Nothing
Set rsRevisions = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Me.Requery 'reload changed data
End Sub
```

[image]

```
'results
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FirmWareRevisionID |      Version       |      Category      |     Processor      |           RevisionDate            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | 1                  |                  1 |                  1 |                         1/22/2024 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | 1                  |                  2 |                  1 |                         1/22/2024 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 | 1                  |                  1 |                  2 |                         1/22/2024 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 | 1                  |                  2 |                  2 |                         1/22/2024 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 25 | 2                  |                  1 |                  1 |              3/10/2024 3:22:49 AM |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 26 | 2                  |                  1 |                  1 |              3/10/2024 3:22:49 AM |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I wanted to demonstrate more general code like public functions and saved parameterized queries but doing so required a complete second example.